# Want to use VBScript to search a txt file, then put the info into Excel

Tags: search, vbscript, export-to-excel

I've got literally a million files (all ascii text files) that I need to search within the file for a string. I'd like to put the file name searched, and the string found, into an Excel spreadsheet (to create a directory listing for reference). This will create a reference file for those files (the string we are searching is unique in every file). All the files are in 1 folder on a server.

I haven't written VBScript in forever, and I'm having a hard time getting started. Has anyone run into this before that would have anything to get me started?

Comment: Did you want a search engine in vbscript and the result is stored in HTML ?

Comment: I'd like the result stored in Excel if possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. "All the files are in 1 folder on a server" => loop over all files in that folder
2. Are all files to be processed or is a filter (extension, date, ...) needed
3. Use Instr() an .ReadAll to determine whether the current file contains the string mentioned in "I need to search within the file for a string"
4. One string or a collection of strings? How will the script know the string(s) to search for?
5. .Write Join(Array(File.Name, sFoundWord), csSep) to the output .csv file (no need for Excel.Application, as .CSVs can be imported/read easly)

Comment: 1. Read every file in a folder.
2. All the files to be processed has the same extension.
3. Is it possible to search for part of a string?
4. A single string (actually, and entire line that begins with something).
5. CSV would be much easier, wouldn't it...